Having a Map in view removes transparent top bar
This is a very strange bug, and I have no idea why it's happening.
When I DON'T have a Map in my view, the top bar is transparent (which is the behaviour I want):

If I DO have a Map in my view, the top bar goes to this translucent blurred look:

The basic structure of my view is :
ScrollViewReader { value in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 16)
                    
                    Text("Map")
                    
                    Map(interactionModes: []) {
                        //
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 194)
                    .background(Color.wireframe)
                    .cornerRadius(18)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                .background(Color.white)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}

Anyone have any idea what's going on?
Thanks!

When you add a Map view, which is a representation of a MKMapView, the navigation bar's style may be altered due to the way MKMapView modifies the appearance of the surrounding navigation controller on the UIKit side of things. MKMapView tends to force the navigation bar to become translucent.
Fix: You can set the navigation bar's appearance in your SwiftUI view's 'onAppear' modifier.
.onAppear {
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance }


Unfortunately, even with those changes, it still shows the translucent/blurred top bar.

@user896541
The last resort would be to hide the navigation bar and add a custom back button/navigation bar to suit your needs.
